# C# Winform App Not Working On Other Computers (Mysterious Hang On Startup)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, deployment

I made a winforms app in Visual Studio. This app is a simple Hello World app that changes a button's text to "Hello World" when pressed.

Here is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                button1.Text = "Hello World";
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to open this program on my development computer, everything works fine. I tried running on 10 different Windows PCs with .NET 3.5 installed (my targeted platform) and everyone of them does the same thing.

Once I double click, or right click and run as administrator, it seems like the application does nothing, but I can tell it's doing something because the mouse cursor changes to a wait cursor... and it does this indefinitely. It also spawns 3 processes of the app's name that cannot be terminated. No Error or "this application has stopped working" is ever thrown.

In addition, I am unable to create crash dumps using task manager, process explorer, debugdiag, or procdump. When I try to get a dump using process explorer... it will say "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory". When I try to create with debugdiag... the dumps are 0 bytes and fail when analyzing. When I try to get a dump with procdump... it will just sit there forever.

I even tried trying to force some sort of error this way...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnGuiUnhandedException);
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HandleUnhandledException(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }

        private static void HandleUnhandledException(Object o)
        {
            // TODO: Log it!
            Exception e = o as Exception;

            if (e != null)
            {

            }
        }

        private static void OnUnhandledException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            HandleUnhandledException(e.ExceptionObject);
        }

        private static void OnGuiUnhandedException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            HandleUnhandledException(e.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Later I tried putting a MessageBox and a return in the program.cs at the beginning of the Main() function. It still did the same thing on all 10 PC's. So I figured that when the program is ran, it never actually hits this:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

After all this, I wonder if it has to do anything with my Visual Studio setup or configuration.

Steps I took:

1. I created new winforms app in Visual Studio 2015
2. I changed .Net platform to 3.5
3. I coded simple app as show above
4. Under configuration manager I changed to x86
5. I built in debug and release mode

After this, I tried 3 deployment methods:

- Copied the whole release folder to another computer
- Tried ClickOnce technology
- Tried InstallShield Limited

All of these did not work. They all do the same thing... spawn 3 processes with the same name that cannot be terminated unless I restart my computer. Cannot create dumps to see what the problem is. Hangs indefinitely when I run and does not display any errors or windows.  ClickOnce and InstallShield never go through any sort of wizard. They just hang indefinitely too...

I tried targeting the 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2 .NET versions too on my friends' PC and I am getting the same situation. These PCs are windows 7 and 8.1. Why is my simple HelloWorld application doing this? Is it something in my configuration on Visual Studio?

Comment: There's really no need to mark edits to your post with "Edit" or anything else.  Other users will see that your post has been edited and can check the revision history manual.  I've removed that unnecessary stuff and made other minor improvements.  But overall, it's a pretty good post.

Comment: "Under configuration manager I changed to x86". Is your machine 32 or 64 bit? Are the other machines 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @ChrisF My machine is 64 bit. 8 out of 10 of my friends machine are 64 bit. I also tried doing 64 bit, but same situation still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I have seemed to solved the issue finally. The problem was that when I created my new project. It always targeted 4.5.2. Then I would go to the project settings and change the framework version from there.

When I select any other framework other than 4.5.2 before I create the project, it works.

I do not know why, but it fixed it for me.